"Pip install -r /code/requirements.txt" inside docker raises error
So, I'm running this command inside docker image: pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
It raises following warning and after that the error:
 > [5/7] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt:
17.75 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/fastapi/
33.39 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/fastapi/
49.51 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/fastapi/
66.64 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/fastapi/
85.77 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/fastapi/
100.9 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fastapi==0.110.0 (from versions: none)
100.9 ERROR: No matching distribution found for fastapi==0.110.0

    ------
    Dockerfile:11
    --------------------
       9 |
      10 |     RUN pip install --upgrade pip
      11 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
      12 |
      13 |     COPY ./ /code/src
    --------------------
    ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

If I'm installing requierments.txt outside docker with command above all libraries are being installed, yet inside docker it causes the error.
Full docker file:
FROM python:3.11

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code/src

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./ /code/src
ENV PYTHONPATH /code/src

RUN chmod a+x run.sh
CMD ["./run.sh"]

What should I do?

can you show us whole error trace

what is your pypi server, is it private one ? you can go in docker shell and run install and see if this is working or not

@sahasrara62 I didn't setup any private pypi servers, I think you can see it in the warning since the host of HHTPSConnectionPool is pypi.org. Do you recommend me to setup the private one?


connection broken by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")

This error suggests that it is a server timeout error.
You can try increasing timeout :
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade --default-timeout=100 -r  /code/requirements.txt


Another approach:
Disabling ipv6, and using ipv4 to connec to pypi.
(It seems it is a well-known bug)
So, basically when pip uses ipv6 it takes longer time to connect, compared to ipv4.
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1


Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue, now I'm just getting the same warning except  "read timeout=100.0".

is this error happening only when it comes to installing fastapi or with other packages too? Have you tried without fastapi ?

Yeah any package causes the warning

I have updated my answer, if that doesn't work either, can you try to install packages without upgrading pip

Second approach updated pip faster then it was updated before, but didn't change the Warning or the Error. As you suggested I deleted the RUN pip install --upgrade pip line, however it didn't help either.
